# Are deviate/variate/draw/realisation synonyms for each other?

Tags: random-variable, simulation, terminology

When talking about random variables,  are the words deviate, variate, draw, realization all proper terminology and equivalent to each other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say these are mostly synonyms. There might be some weak shades of meaning, like "draw" mostly used in the context of simulation.

Comment: "Deviate" carries a sense of being measured relative to a mean, most commonly of a normal or Gaussian distribution.